Tring to upgrade from 22.04 lts to new noble version showing error talk to administration
Oh no! Something has gone wrong.
A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator
This message is shown

[edit] your question with further information. What are you upgrading from and what commands did you use? The upgrade from 22.04LTS to 24.04 LTS would be available until the summer when the first point release (24.04.1) drops. To do it sooner you need to use the command-line and accept the risk that things may go wrong

I did from 22.04 lts

I did it using cmd i didnt know it can go wrong youtubers dont tell it can go wrong  pls help me

you backed up your data, right? What command did you use? Don't add to the comment trail (which is for others to ask you questions) [EDIT] your question with any further information

Thankyou for helping i now reinstalled the system on 22.04 i was not having backups lost my data  I should stop watch youtube

You're welcome. Sadly I think that was your best option to re-install 22.04. A salutary lesson but I think for the future you should install Timeshift a backu; restore utility you can download using the command sudo apt install timeshift in terminal. A guide to Timeshift is available in this resource

Does this answer your question? Cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 23.10 to Ubuntu 24.04 (Answer also covers upgrade from 22.04)
